# Passing a variable value from one page to another in php

Tags: php, html, variables

I have this code that will show any product containing the word adidas in my database at a specified table. So the next thing is to link the code of the product to the certain product and then have it link to another page so that it will populate automatically recurring that product code.

I've tried the session method but it only gives me the last code. If there is this code: `cha3` `cha2` `cha1`, it will give me `cha1` no matter what I've clicked on the other page. What I wanted to do is if you click product with the code `cha1` it will populate the `produto.php` with the details of `cha1`. Sorry if you don't understand. I'll post s snippet of code to give some idea. It's "clean" because I tried a lot of methods and until now nothing worked.

```
  <?php

        $ligaBD=odbc_connect('basededadospap','','');
        $sql="SELECT * FROM produto WHERE nome_produto LIKE '%ADIDAS%'";
        $resultado=odbc_exec($ligaBD,$sql);
        ?>
        <div class="row shop_box-top">

        <?php
        while (odbc_fetch_row($resultado))

    {
        $codigo = odbc_result($resultado,1);
        $nome = odbc_result($resultado,2);
        $preco = odbc_result($resultado,4);
        $foto1 = odbc_result($resultado,9);      



        ?>


            <div class="col-md-3 shop_box"> <a href="produto.php" >
                <img src=" <?php echo $foto1;?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                <span class="new-box">
                    <span class="new-label">Novo</span>
                </span>
                <?php $codigo ?>
                <div class="shop_desc">
                    <h3><a href="produto.php> <?php echo $nome;?>  </a></h3>


                    <span class="actual"><?php echo $preco; ?></span><br>

                </div>

            </a></div>


        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you can use `GET` parameters in your links to pass whatever information you want on your other page.

```
<a href="produto.php?code=<?php echo $variable_with_the_code; ?>">
    <?php echo $nome;?>
</a>
```

You can add more `GET` params if you need. On the other page you can access these values like `$_GET['code']`.

Comment: Thank you so much man , you just made my life so much easier,really, thanks a lot man !